# Inverted Y-axis on Modix BIG-120X V2

Tags: y-axis

I'm almost done putting together this big behemoth, and I came to find out that the Y-axis is inverted. It goes away from the end stop. I've tried everything I could find but can't figure out why. It looks like it's just the Y-axis motor port on the board because I've swapped the X-axis and the Y-axis and it has the problem with the X-axis at that point.

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! A little more informaion would be more than welcome (by [edit]), is this an existing branded printer or a a DIY, are you compiling the firmware yourself, if so what firmware. Please be a little more specific to better answer your question.